# Non-exhaustive patterns error with empty list

Tags: haskell

I am declaring a new type for memory and then use a function to update it. The program compiles and works fine when I add values to the list, but if my list is empty I get the error:

```
*** Exception: Non-exhaustive patterns in function update
```

Here is my code, if you can please help me:

```
type Name = [Char]
type Memory = [(Name, Integer)]

update :: Name -> Integer -> Memory -> Memory
update n x (h:t)
    | fst h == n  = (n, x) : t
    | h : t == [] = [(n, x)]
    | otherwise   = h : update n x t
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because your code doesn't cover the empty list case.
In particular this: `h:t == []` will never evaluate to `True`. `h:t` is a pattern which will only match a non-empty list: it binds `h` to the head of the list and `t` to the rest of the list.

So your function needs to handle three cases:

```
update n x [] = (n,x):[]                        -- empty list
update n x (h:t) | n == fst h = (n,x):t         -- key equal to n
                 | otherwise  = h:update n x t  -- key not equal to n
```

Comment: also it needs to add to the second check n== fst h